# How to make the width of stacked multiple div dynamicly adjust to the longest content among them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make the width of stacked multiple div adjust to the longest content dynamically like this:
[image: Target rendering]

I have googled it. `inline-block` is suggested. With bootstrap4, here is my first try:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
    div.cls{
        display: inline;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="cls">
            <b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls">
            111
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="cls">
            <b>bbb</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls">
            222
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="cls">
            <b>ccccc</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls">
            33333333333
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div class="cls">
            <b>dddddddddd</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls">
           4 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Regrettably, it does not work:

[image]

So I switched my idea. Why not use `flex-grid` `row` to hold 2 stacked div: `abc`s and `123`s?

```html
    <div class="row justify-content-start">
        <div>
            <div>
                <b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</b>
            </div>
            <div>
                <b>bbb</b>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                111
            </div>
            <div>
                222
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Actually, it works. 
[image]

**What bothers me is that the implementation is kind of lengthy and jumbled. Is there a better way to achieve the goal?**

Hope for your help. :-)

Comment: Use a table. It's pretty clear that is what you have here.

Comment: How to adjust the bootstrap table cell width? Could you give a demo

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you need a table layout:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="d-table">
    <div class="d-table-row ">
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
            <b>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
            111
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-table-row">
        <div class="cl d-table-cells">
            <b>bbb</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
            222
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-table-row">
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
            <b>ccccc</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
            33333333333
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-table-row">
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
            <b>dddddddddd</b>
        </div>
        <div class="cls d-table-cell">
           4 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```